# Summation up to a variable integer: How to get the coefficients?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is an example. I want to know if there is a general way to deal with this kind of problems.

Suppose I have a function (a ε     ℜ) :

```
f[a_, n_Integer, m_Integer] := Sum[a^i k[i],{i,0,n}]^m
```

[image]

And I need a closed form for the coefficient a^p. What is the better way to proceed?

**Note 1**:In this particular case, one could go manually trying to represent the sum through [`Multinomial[ ]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Multinomial.html), but it seems difficult to write down the Multinomial terms for a variable number of arguments, and besides, I want Mma to do it.

**Note 2**: Of course

```
 Collect[f[a, 3, 4], a]
```

Will do, but only for a given `m` and `n`.

**Note 3**: This question is related to [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35591/a-series-solution-of-the-differential-equation-fracd2uxdx2-uxn-0). My application is different, but probably the same methods apply. So, feel free to answer both with a single shot.

**Note 4**:

You can model the multinomial theorem with a function like:

```
f[n_, m_] := 
  Sum[KroneckerDelta[m - Sum[r[i], {i, n}]] 
   (Multinomial @@ Sequence@Array[r, n]) 
     Product[x[i]^r[i], {i, n}], 
  Evaluate@(Sequence @@ Table[{r[i], 0, m}, {i, 1, n}])];
```

So, for example

```
f[2,3]
```

is the cube of a binomial

```
x[1]^3+ 3 x[1]^2 x[2]+ 3 x[1] x[2]^2+ x[2]^3
```

Comment: Do you know the roots of the resulting polynomial? If so, the answer is trivial.

Comment: @Yoda the k[i] are in general functions that I wish to found later using relations for these coefficients coming from other approximations. So, no, the roots are not known :(

Comment: `Collect[f[a, 3, 4], a]` does nothing because you have defined f to take a `Real` as first argument, not a symbol.

Comment: @Sjoerd Just remove the `_Real` part, and it does. I'm editing for clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coefficient by `a^k` can be viewed as derivative of order `k` at zero divided by `k!`. In version 8, there is a function [`BellY`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BellY.html), which allows to construct a derivative at a point for composition of functions, out of derivatives of individual components. Basically, for `f[g[x]]` and expanding around `x==0` we find `Derivative[p][Function[x,f[g[x]]][0]` as

```
BellY[ Table[ { Derivative[k][f][g[0]], Derivative[k][g][0]}, {k, 1, p} ] ]/p!
```

This is also known as generalized Bell polynomial, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

In the case at hand:

```
f[a_, n_Integer, m_Integer] := Sum[a^i k[i], {i, 0, n}]^m

With[{n = 3, m = 4, p = 7}, 
  BellY[ Table[{FactorialPower[m, s] k[0]^(m - s), 
      If[s <= n, s! k[s], 0]}, {s, 1, p}]]/p!] // Distribute

(*
Out[80]= 4 k[1] k[2]^3 + 12 k[1]^2 k[2] k[3] + 12 k[0] k[2]^2 k[3] + 
 12 k[0] k[1] k[3]^2
*)

With[{n = 3, m = 4, p = 7}, Coefficient[f[a, n, m], a, p]]

(*
Out[81]= 4 k[1] k[2]^3 + 12 k[1]^2 k[2] k[3] + 12 k[0] k[2]^2 k[3] + 
 12 k[0] k[1] k[3]^2
*)
```

Doing it this way is more computationally efficient than building the entire expression and extracting coefficients.

---

**EDIT** The approach here outlined will work for symbolic orders `n` and `m`, but requires explicit value for `p`. When using it is this circumstances, it is better to replace `If` with its `Piecewise` analog, e.g. `Boole`:

```
With[{p = 2}, 
 BellY[Table[{FactorialPower[m, s] k[0]^(m - s), 
     Boole[s <= n] s! k[s]}, {s, 1, p}]]/p!]

(* 1/2 (Boole[1 <= n]^2 FactorialPower[m, 2] k[0]^(-2 + m)
     k[1]^2 + 2 m Boole[2 <= n] k[0]^(-1 + m) k[2]) *)
```

Comment: @Sasha: I think belisarius wanted an expression for a general unknown `m` and `n`, not with values substituted.

Comment: @yoda I realize that, `m` and `n` do not have to be explicit, only `p` has to be. For instance, `With[{p = 7}, 
  BellY[Table[{FactorialPower[m, s] k[0]^(m - s), 
      Boole[s <= n] s! k[s]}, {s, 1, p}]]/p!] /. 
 FactorialPower[m_, k_Integer] :> Product[m - i, {i, 0, k - 1}]`

Comment: @Sasha: That is really neat. I can't try it as I don't have mma8, but I'm deleting my answer, as my claim that it probably couldn't be done was incorrect.

Comment: @belisarius For `p==2` I am getting `(1/2)*((-1 + m)*m*Boole[1 <= n]^2*k[0]^(-2 + m)*k[1]^2 + 2*m*Boole[2 <= n]*k[0]^(-1 + m)*k[2])`, which does not depend on `s`.

Comment: @belisarius The issue is that `If` is `HoldAll` and `s` lingers around. Using equivalent formulation with `Boole` or `Piecewise` will work fine: `With[{p = 2}, BellY[Table[{FactorialPower[m, s] k[0]^(m - s), Boole[s <= n] s! k[s]}, {s, 1, p}]]/p!]`